# No such file or directory error on unibo powertools dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I run the program in colab and it getting error in base_path in accesing data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.io
import math
import os
import ntpath
import sys
import logging
import time
import sys

```
from importlib import reload
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import gradient_descent_v2
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Masking
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, LambdaCallback


IS_COLAB = True

if IS_COLAB:
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive')
    data_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/battery-state-estimation/battery-state-estimation/"
else:
    data_path = "../"

sys.path.append(data_path)
from data_processing.unibo_powertools_data import UniboPowertoolsData, CycleCols
from data_processing.model_data_handler import ModelDataHandler


dataset = UniboPowertoolsData(
    test_types=['S'],
    chunk_size=1000000,
    lines=[37, 40],
    charge_line=37,
    discharge_line=40,
    base_path='/content/drive/MyDrive/battery-state-estimation/battery-state-estimation'
)
```

This the code run in colabs.
base_path is not suitable to run the code. can anyone fix the problem

```
2022/06/26 16:36:18 [DEBUG]: Start loading data with lines: [37, 40], types: ['S'] and chunksize: 1000000...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b98ba86c5d3b> in <module>()
      5     charge_line=37,
      6     discharge_line=40,
----> 7     base_path='/content/drive/MyDrive/battery-state-estimation/battery-state-estimation'
      8 )

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    705                 encoding=ioargs.encoding,
    706                 errors=errors,
--> 707                 newline="",
    708             )
    709 else:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/battery-state-estimation/battery-state-estimationdata/unibo-powertools-dataset/unibo-/test_result.csv'
```

Comment: https://github.com/MichaelBosello/battery-rul-estimation

Comment: you have `"My Drive"` and `"MyDrive"`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.